# RecyclerView duplicates items when changing an item's UI

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to change the background of an ImageView (like button) when it is clicked. However, the background is changing immediately when the like icon is clicked then immediately the recyclerview is refreshed and the items are duplicated (with the default icon)

I tried the following from answers to similar questions:

1- adding some conditions to the onBindViewHolder to identify the cliked item

2- postAdapter.setHasStableIds(true)

3- using  postAdapter.notifyItemChanged(position)

4- overriding the following methods in the adapter class:

```
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position;
}


@Override
public void setHasStableIds(boolean hasStableIds) {
    super.setHasStableIds(hasStableIds);
}
```

I tried each of the above separately and then all at once, nothing worked and the problem persisted :/

the code is complicated so these are the relevant parts:

1- Adapter class:

note that, it has an interface and an interface instance. the instance is used in the likeImage.setOnClickListener in the inner ViewHolder class where the clicked and clickedPositions are set too;

```
public class PostRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PostRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {

public interface ClickListener{
    public void click(View view, int position);
}

private ArrayList<Post> postList;
private Context context;
private ClickListener clickListener;
private int clickedItemPosition = -1;
private boolean clicked = false;



public PostRecyclerAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Post> postList){
    this.context = context;
    this.postList = postList;
}

public void onClickListener(ClickListener clickListener){
    this.clickListener = clickListener;
}


@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    return new ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.post_item, parent, false));
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    if(clicked){
        if(clickedItemPosition == position){
            holder.likeImage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.like_filled);
            clicked = false;
            return;
        }
    }

    if(!clicked) {

        Post post = postList.get(position);

        holder.username.setText(post.getUsername());
        holder.date.setText(post.getDateAdded().toString());
        holder.description.setText(post.getDescription());
        holder.likeNum.setText(String.valueOf(post.getLikeNum()));
        holder.commentNum.setText(String.valueOf(post.getCommentNum()));

        Picasso.get()
                .load(Uri.parse(post.getImageUri()))
                .placeholder(R.drawable.download)
                .into(holder.postImage);

        //        holder.userImage.setText(post.getDateAdded().toString());
        //        holder.postImage.setText(post.getDateAdded().toString());

    }


}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position;
}


@Override
public void setHasStableIds(boolean hasStableIds) {
    super.setHasStableIds(hasStableIds);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
   if(postList != null)
       return postList.size();
   return 0;
}


// Inner View class
class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    ImageView userImage, postImage, commentImage, likeImage ;
    TextView username, date, description, commentNum, likeNum;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        userImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_item_userImage);
        username = itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_item_username);
        date = itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_item_date);
        postImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_item_postImage);
        likeNum= itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_item_likesNum);
        commentNum = itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_item_commentsNum);
        description = itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_item_description);
        commentImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_item_comments);
        likeImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_item_likes);

        commentImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Toast.makeText(context, "commentClicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if(clickListener != null) {
                    clickedItemPosition = getAdapterPosition();
                    clickListener.click(view, getAdapterPosition());

                }
            }
        });

        likeImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "LikeClicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if(clickListener != null) {
                    clicked = true;
                    clickedItemPosition = getAdapterPosition();
                    clickListener.click(view, getAdapterPosition());

                }

            }
        });
    }
}
}
```

2- where the onClickListener interface method is implemented:

```
    @Override
public void click(View view, int position) {

    switch(view.getId()){

        case R.id.post_item_likes:
            likeUnlike(view, position);
            break;

        case R.id.post_item_comments:
            break;


    }
```

3- within the likeUnlike method I attemp to change the icon:

```
 view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.like_filled);
 postAdapter.notifyItemChanged(position);
```

- this is the full likeUnlike method:

  ```
  postCommentReference.whereEqualTo("userID", user.getUid())
          .addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
              @Override
              public void onEvent(@javax.annotation.Nullable QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots, @javax.annotation.Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {

                  // within the comment sub-collection of the clicked post

                  if(e != null){
                      Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Exception "+e.toString() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  }else{


                      if(queryDocumentSnapshots.isEmpty()){
                          // create a DOCUMENT for the comment:
                          DocumentReference likeDocReference = postCommentReference.document(user.getUid());

                          // create new like
                          Like like = new Like();
                          like.setPostID(post.getPostID());
                          like.setUserID(user.getUid());
                          like.setUsername(UserUtils.getInstance().username);
                          like.setLikeID(likeDocReference.getId());

                          // add like to db
                          likeDocReference.set(like);

                          //increment LikeNum
                          post.setLikeNum(post.getLikeNum()+1);
                          postReference.document(post.getPostID()).update("likeNum", post.getLikeNum())
                                  .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                      @Override
                                      public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                          if(task.isSuccessful()){
                                              Log.d("home_fragment_likeNum", "onComplete: likeNum is updated");
                                          }else{
                                              Log.d("home_fragment_likeNum", "onComplete:  Exception: "+task.getException());
                                          }
                                      }
                                  });

                          // change icon
                          view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.like_filled);
                          postAdapter.notifyItemChanged(position);
                          return;
                      }else{


                      }
                  }
              }
          });}
  ```